# True/False doesn't carry over to a multiplication?

Tags: r

```
> df1$Coupon.Rate[1]==0.103
[1] TRUE

> df1$Face.Value[1]==100
[1] TRUE

> df1$Coupon.Rate[1]*df1$Face.Value[1]==10.3
[1] FALSE
```

How is it possible for true/false values to not be consistent like this?
The formats are num and int.
Don't exactly know how to describe the problem apart from a logical inconsistency...

Comment: [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558#9508558)

Comment: Yes thanks! Kind of depressing though to do data checks!